# sql query to find MTD and YTD for Nepali date where dates are in AD at database level

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a requirement to find MTD and YTD for Nepali date(BS) but all the dates on sql server database are in English Date(AD) format.How to achieve it?Below code gives MTD and YTD for english date?

```
SELECT BILL_DATE,
PRODCODE,
QUANTITY,
SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(BILL_DATE)) AS MTD,
SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(BILL_DATE)) AS YTD
FROM BILLDET
WHERE (PRODCODE = 'MFS-10') AND (BILL_DATE >= '2019-4-14')
ORDER BY BILL_DATE
```

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i convert English date to Nepali date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452172/how-do-i-convert-english-date-to-nepali-date)