# Conversion of AD to BS

Tags: python

How do I convert English Date i.e. AD to BS?
Is there any specific formula to convert between these?

I tried adding 20716 days to the AD date but it always gave me an difference of either 3 days more or 5 Days more.Could anybody please help me out?

Comment: what's BS? Do you mean AD/BC?

Comment: @aviya.developer It is the Bikram Sambat Nepali calendar

Comment: @aviya.developer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikram_Samvat

Comment: @ry oh super nice. interesting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i convert English date to Nepali date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452172/how-do-i-convert-english-date-to-nepali-date)

Comment: you can use  'pip install nepali-date'  https://pypi.org/project/nepali-date/

Comment: Some popular libraries for performing this conversion in Python are py-bsdate, datetime_converter, etc. These libraries can help you perform accurate and reliable conversions between English (AD) and Bikram Sambat (BS) dates.